# Lex program to remove comments from input file

Tags: c, regex, comments, lex

Currently I am trying to remove all forms of comments from an input file. However I cannot figure out how to remove a particular form specifically this form "{comment}". I know on this site there are plenty of Regex examples to remove multi/single line comments but I cannot figure it out.

Input:

```
       int j=100;
       /* comment needs to be removed*/
       int c = 200;


      /*
       *comment needs to be removed 
       */

      count = count + 1;

     {comment needs to be removed}

      i++;
```

Output:

```
int j=100;
int c =200;
count = count +1;
i++;
```

I already was able to remove the first 2 comments but not the last one. I tried using the regex of `"{}".*` however that did not work for my last comment `{comment}`. Is there a regex that can be used to rectify this or am I better creating a function in C and handling the situation that way?

Comment: Comment is neither in the form `/*...*/` nor in the form `//` but in the form of `{}`?

Comment: Comment's are in the specification for a language. `/* .. */` and `// ...` are C++ style comments, where `{..}` is not a comment in the C lang spec. Also, you can't just match comments without matching quoted strings since strings hide comment syntax. I guess you could treat `{` `}` as comment delimiters to be parsed as well, but it is highly unusual. Let me know if you need the C regex.

Comment: @josephV: Have you tried reading up about regular expressions? `"{}".*` means: an open brace followed by a close brace followed by any amount of anything other than a newline. So it would match `{}This is a comment`. I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @user10334659 yes that was part of the requirements it was baffling to me as well

Comment: @sln yes I would very much appreciate the C regex!

Comment: @rici yes I am in the midst of learning regex, my example was just a guess!

Comment: @JosephV  - posted a regex for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of comment is contained within `{` and `}`, but you should be careful.

Try this regex.

```
\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|{[^{}]*?}
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/AXxFHc/2)

Answer (score 0):

***== Note that for all the regex below, matches must be replaced by `$2` (capture group 2) which write's back the non-comments. This effectively removes all the comments ==***

Here is a standard C++ comment parser.
This is the extended version that preserves formatting.

raw:

```
(?m)((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//)))?|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//))|(?=\r?\n))))+)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|(?:\r?\n|[\S\s])[^/"'\\\s]*)
```

delimited `/ regex /`

```
/(?m)((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|\/\*|\/\/)))?|\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|\/\*|\/\/))|(?=\r?\n))))+)|((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?:\r?\n(?:(?=(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:\/\*|\/\/))|[^\/"'\\\r\n]*))+|[^\/"'\\\r\n]+)+|[\S\s][^\/"'\\\r\n]*)/
```

Demo PCRE:    https://regex101.com/r/UldYK5/1
Demo Python:  https://regex101.com/r/avfSfB/1

**----------------------------------------------------------**

This a modified version of the above, adding your `{ .. }` comments.
(*This is not recommended since `{}` is scoping syntax in C*)

raw:

```
(?m)((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//|\{)))?|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//|\{))|(?=\r?\n))|\{[\S\s]*?\}(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//|\{)))?))+)|((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?:\r?\n(?:(?=(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:/\*|//|\{))|[^/"'\\\r\n{]*))+|[^/"'\\\r\n{]+)+|[\S\s][^/"'\\\r\n{]*)
```

delimited `/ regex /`

```
/(?m)((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|\/\*|\/\/|\{)))?|\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|\/\*|\/\/|\{))|(?=\r?\n))|\{[\S\s]*?\}(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|\/\*|\/\/|\{)))?))+)|((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?:\r?\n(?:(?=(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:\/\*|\/\/|\{))|[^\/"'\\\r\n{]*))+|[^\/"'\\\r\n{]+)+|[\S\s][^\/"'\\\r\n{]*)/
```

Demo PCRE (using your sample text): https://regex101.com/r/xHTua7/1

Readable version with comments

```
    (?m)                             # Multi-line modifier
    (                                # (1 start), Comments 
         (?:
              (?: ^ [ \t]* )?                  # <- To preserve formatting
              (?:
                   /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
                   [^*]* \*+
                   (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
                   /                                # End /* .. */ comment
                   (?:                              # <- To preserve formatting 
                        [ \t]* \r? \n                                      
                        (?=
                             [ \t]*                  
                             (?:
                                  \r? \n 
                               |  /\*
                               |  // 
                               |  \{                               # Added:  for {} comments
                             )
                        )
                   )?
                |                                 # or,
                   //                               # Start // comment
                   (?:                              # Possible line-continuation
                        [^\\] 
                     |  \\ 
                        (?: \r? \n )?
                   )*?
                   (?:                              # End // comment
                        \r? \n                               
                        (?=                              # <- To preserve formatting
                             [ \t]*                          
                             (?:
                                  \r? \n 
                               |  /\*
                               |  // 
                               |  \{                               # Added:  for {}  comments
                             )
                        )
                     |  (?= \r? \n )
                   )
                |                                 # or,
                   \{                               # Added:  Start { .. } comment
                   [\S\s]*? 
                   \}                               # Added:  End { .. } comment
                   (?:                              # <- To preserve formatting 
                        [ \t]* \r? \n                                      
                        (?=
                             [ \t]*                  
                             (?:
                                  \r? \n 
                               |  /\*
                               |  // 
                               |  \{                               # Added:  for {} comments
                             )
                        )
                   )?
              )
         )+                               # Grab multiple comment blocks if need be
    )                                # (1 end)

 |                                 ## OR

    (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
         # Quotes
         # ======================
         (?:                              # Quote and Non-Comment blocks
              "
              [^"\\]*                          # Double quoted text
              (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
              "
           |                                 # --------------
              '
              [^'\\]*                          # Single quoted text
              (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
              ' 
           |                                 # --------------

              (?:                              # Qualified Linebreak's
                   \r? \n                           
                   (?:
                        (?=                              # If comment ahead just stop
                             (?: ^ [ \t]* )?
                             (?:
                                  /\*
                               |  // 
                               |  \{                               # Added:  for {} comments
                             )
                        )
                     |                                 # or,
                                                         # Added:  [^{] for {} comments
                        [^/"'\\\r\n{]*                   # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                                         # or line continuation (escape + newline)
                   )
              )+
           |                                 # --------------
                                               # Added:  [^{] for {} comments
              [^/"'\\\r\n{]+                   # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                               # or line continuation (escape + newline)

         )+                               # Grab multiple instances

      |                                 # or,
         # ======================
         # Pass through

         [\S\s]                           # Any other char
                                          # Added:  [^{] for {} comments
         [^/"'\\\r\n{]*                   # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                          # or line continuation (escape + newline)

    )                                # (2 end), Non - comments
```